# Titanium - Reset zoom scale in webview

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to programmatically reset the zoom/scale that the user has done in a webview? My issue is when the webview is pinch zoomed in landscape and you rotate the phone, the webview is still zoomed in and in my case, portrait mode is now extremely zoomed in.

I've tried `webview.repaint()` but that seems to do absolutely nothing. I know I can call `webiew.reload()` but that just uses more bandwidth for my server as well as the users data plan so I want to avoid that.

I'm using `Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.3.xxx`, `3.1.3 GA Ti SDK` and compiling for `iOS 7 SDK`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this thread and the fact that there was no way to easily achieve this, I have created a module. It extends the Ti.UI.WebView with two methods, `setZoomLevel()` and `scrollToTop()`. It is very basic at the moment, but I'm planning on extending its functionality gradually.

https://github.com/mwfire/titanium-module-extended-webview

Have a look, it's an alternative to modifying the core code.

Comment: Nice, did you just make this? I would have made a module, but I figured editing the core was going to be more direct and easier..which in my case it was for the time being

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed easier to change the core, but I think with the next SDK update the modifications might be gone. And I wanted to get into that module stuff anyways, so this was a nice starting point ;)

Comment: yea it will definitely be gone next SDK update, I'll have to use this module on our next app release. We just submitted an update yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try at setting the scalesPageToFit property of your webview upon orientation change?

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-property-scalesPageToFit

Comment: I set it in the beginning when I create the webview, I haven't tried setting it after. I'll give it a shot and report back

Comment: Well, setting this property on rotate doesn't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which was a bit more than I wanted to do. I had to actually modify the Titanium SDK obj-c files.

I modified 3 files:

**TiUIWebView.h**

```
-(void)resetZoomScale; //-- added this line to define the function in the header file
```

**TiUIWebView.m**

```
//-- Added this function that will actually handle the resize
- (void)resetZoomScale
{
    [webview.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0]; //-- reset the scroll view back to 1
}
```

**TiUIWebViewProxy.m**

```
//-- Call the resetZoomScale function in TiUIWebView.m file
//-- I believe this also exposes the function to javascript
-(void)resetZoomScale:()args
{
    TiThreadPerformOnMainThread(^{[(TiUIWebView*)[self view] resetZoomScale];}, NO);
}
```

I can now call `myWebView.resetZoomScale();` and whatever pinch/zooming has been done on the web view will be reset back none or 1